# PHP Mysql Joins and Where Clause

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I need help on below statement. I need to put `WHERE items.IID = 8` so that it shows only details pertaining to IID number 8. But when I use `WHERE items.IID = 8`, it is not working. I have to use this type of join as I want to do Sum and Count of some fields. There are 3 tables. 1st is `items`, 2nd is `ItemPurchaseHistory` and 3rd is `ItemIssuedHistory`.

```
SELECT items.IID, items.ItemName, ItemPurchaseHistorySum.SumOfUnitsPurchased, ItemPurchaseHistorySum.SumOfCost,
ItemPurchaseHistoryCount.CountOfUnitsPurchased,
ItemIssuedHistorySum.SumOfUnitsIssued
FROM items

LEFT JOIN (SELECT IID, SUM(UnitsPurchased) AS SumOfUnitsPurchased, SUM(Cost) AS SumOfCost
FROM ItemPurchaseHistory
GROUP BY IID) ItemPurchaseHistorySum ON ItemPurchaseHistorySum.IID = items.IID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT IID, Count(UnitsPurchased) AS CountOfUnitsPurchased
FROM ItemPurchaseHistory
GROUP BY IID) ItemPurchaseHistoryCount ON ItemPurchaseHistoryCount.IID = items.IID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT IID, SUM(UnitsIssued) AS SumOfUnitsIssued
FROM ItemIssuedHistory
GROUP BY IID) ItemIssuedHistorySum ON ItemIssuedHistorySum.IID = items.IID
```

WHERE item.IID = $_GET['id']

```
ORDER BY items.IID ASC
```

Comment: Show us where you put that `WHRE`-statement.

Comment: Between the `FROM` and the `GROUP BY` is where the `WHERE` clause goes.

Comment: It is working when I put 8 in Where Clause but not working when I use $_GET['id']

Comment: It is working when I use 8 in Where Clause as below. But not working when I want to use $_GET['id']. I tried doing $id = $_GET['id']. But it is not working. When I do it like $id = 8 and then use $id in Where Clause below, it works. But not with $GET['id'].